# does tensorflow allocate memory for tensorarrays created by split()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'd like to take a tensorarray, concatenate it, do an operation on it, and then turn it into a tensorarray. This is in order to batch over inputs of different sizes. (these inputs are sets of points, not sequences.)

I was wondering if tensorflow would actually copy data over when splitting and concatenating, or if it would just save the sizes and operate on a single tensor, presenting a "view" to the programmer.

Comment: This depends on the operations you're executing; please give us a small, stand-alone code example.  Also, why not simply try it and track your memory usage during the operations?

Comment: That said, in general, the underlying system (Python) will allocate new memory for the result of each operation, releasing temporary (intermediate) variables once they're no longer needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Prune pointed out, this is on a case by case basis (depending on if in-place algorithms is possible or preferred) and you will need to look into Compute method of each operation to find out.

For example, for Concat, the output is separately allocated:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/concat_op.cc#L130

But for BiasAdd, the output reuses the same allocated memory of the input:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/bias_op.cc#L77